# Python не подгружает модуль tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Всем привет! В документации написано, что tkinter имеется в стандартном наборе библиотек Python. Но при импорте модуля, интерпретатор выдаёт ошибки, что такого модуля не существует. Пробовал различные варианты:

- import _tkinter
- import tkinter
- import Tkinter

Ошибка везде одинаковая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter
```

Как правильно импортировать модуль? Или его нужно установить?

Comment: Какой дистрибутив Python у вас установлен?

Comment: В какой операционной системе используете python? В линукс возможно надо установить пакет, содержащий Tkinter

Comment: @AntonKulago Из сообщения об ошибке видно, что виндовс.

Comment: При установке Python возможно не была установлена галка для установки tkinter.

Comment: @insolor поможет только переустановка или можно доустановить пакет?

Comment: @insolor спасибо, помогла переустановка. Интересно, почему для одной библиотеки выдели целую строку при установки :D

Comment: @ChapeauClaque, потому что кому-то может быть нужен самый минимальный набор - только стандартная библиотека.

Answer (score 1):

При установке Python на Windows нужно зайти в "Customize installation" и проверить чтобы стояла галка напротив "tcl/tk and IDLE". Если первоначально Python был установлен без этой галки, переустановка с включенной галкой должна решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что не шарю.
Скорее всего, установил не полный пакет питона или что-то в таком духе, поэтому там просто нет tkinter (Было похожее с пайгеймом, там надо было скачать файл и установить).
Можешь проверить, есть ли он у тебя вообще в файлах.
Если нет, то тут, наверное, поможет переустановка питона.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать tkinter в ОС Linux, надо установить пакет python-tk.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже сначала столкнулся с этой проблемой. Справился так:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Также это может помочь:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

P.S. отвечая @insolor[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если с `import tkinter` пишет что нет такого модуля, то ваши варианты тоже будут выдавать такую ошибку.

Comment: @insolor, посмотрите прикрепленные файлы. В теории вы скорее всего правы - должно либо загружать со всеми вариантами, или не загружать вовсе.

Comment: Нет, на практике работает как и должно работать. При импорте через `import tkinter` нужно писать `root = tkinter.Tk()`, при `import tkinter as tk`  - `root = tk.Tk()`, при  `from tkinter import *` - `root = Tk()`. Если модуля tkinter вообще нет, то во всех трех случаях будет ошибка как в вопросе на этапе импорта.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pacman -S tk
```

Можно попробовать для Арча, Манджаро.

Answer (score 0):

На Ubuntu надо устанавливать так

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```